# How to use Density Functional Theory to get the correct energy spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, many-body, density-functional-theory

I'm having some trouble understanding how DFT can be used to obtain results for electronic structure calculations. We can assume that we're studying an $N$ electron atom with a fixed nucleus and want to get its ground state energy.

In Kohn-Sham DFT, we imagine a *fictitious* system of non-interacting particles, such that $\Psi(\mathbf r_1, \ldots, \mathbf r_N) = \prod_i \psi_i(\mathbf r)$.
From this, we can construct the KS equations: $$\left[ -\frac 12 \nabla^2  + V_{ext}(\mathbf r) + \int \frac{ \rho(\mathbf r')}{|\mathbf r- \mathbf r'|} d \mathbf r' + V_{XC}(\mathbf r) \right] \psi_i = E_i \psi_i.  $$ The middle term is the Hartree potential. These equations can be solved *self consistently*. First, guess the form of the electron density and approximate the exchange-correlation potential. Then, at each iteration we solve these equations (I.E by diagonalisation) to get the $\psi_i$  and then update the density to construct a new Hamiltonian since $\rho(\mathbf r) = \sum_{i=1}^N |\psi_i(\mathbf r)|^2$. Until the eigenvalues converge. This allows us to get the **correct ground state charge density** (through the variational theorem).

What I don't understand is how to proceed from there. Are the eigenvalues of the KS Hamiltonian equal to the energy spectrum of the *true system*? If so, why? And if not, how is the correct ground state energy found from here?

Comment: See e.g. [A bird's-eye view of density-functional theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0211443), on page 34, equation 73 or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohn%E2%80%93Sham_equations)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the Khon-Sham equations yields the Khon-Sham orbitals $\psi_i$ and the KS orbital energies $\varepsilon_i$. The groundstate energy of the N-particle system is then obtained as
$$
E = \sum_i^N\varepsilon_i - E_H[\rho] + E_{xc}[\rho] - \int \frac{\delta E_{xc}[\rho]}{\delta\rho(r)}
\rho(r)dr$$

with $\rho(r)=\sum_i^N|\psi_i(r)|^2$, $E_H[\rho]=\frac{e^2}{2}\int dr \int dr' \frac{\rho(r)\rho(r')}{|r-r'|}$. Check also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohn%E2%80%93Sham_equations) for the definitions.

You do not obtain excited states of the N-particle system. A method to obtain excited states/energies is [time-dependent DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-dependent_density_functional_theory).

But the problematic part is actually the exchange correlaction energy functional $E_{xc}[\rho]$. The correct expression for this functional is unknown (except for the case of a uniform electron gas) and there exists a whole zoo of exchange-correlation functionals that have to be used as approximations in place of the unknown correct exchange correlation functional. For this reason the groundstate energy obtained via KS-DFT is usually an approximation. Finding/defining new functionals that yield good results over a large range of different systems is still an active field of research.

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you very much.